# cf ic login erroring out with network error

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

$:~$ cf ic -v login shows that 
...Retrieving client certificates for IBM Containers...
[http-req]2016/08/21 13:39:59 HTTP Request Url: https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443/v3/tlskey
[http-req]2016/08/21 13:39:59 HTTP Request body: null...

http-resp]2016/08/21 13:39:59 Error: Get https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443/v3/tlskey: Forbidden
FAILED

Error getting response, check your network connection

Comment: Please provide more information so that we can answer your question. What were you trying to do when you got this error?

Comment: I was just trying to do a cf ic login after cf login. cf login is successful but cf ic login errors out.

Comment: It would help if you could provide some context about what you're doing, what you want to do, and what you've tried. As it stands your question doesn't really contain a question.

Comment: I am trying to follow the steps given in this page.https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_login.html#container_cli_login__option2_li   . idea is to connect to my bluemix repository and try pushing and pulling some docker images. For that the steps ask me to do a cf ic login. That is the place where I am stuck

Comment: Do you experience the same issue using the new 'bx' CLI? http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html

Comment: Issue got resolved. It was a two fold issue. a) the machine was accessing internet through proxy. 2)docker engine was old version (1.6). I upgraded to 1.12 and moved to a machine with direct internet connection and cf ic commands are running fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, it was a two-fold issue:

- The machine was accessing internet through proxy.
- The Docker engine was an old version (1.6).

The Docker engine was upgraded to 1.12 and moved to a machine with direct Internet connection